# Export Excel workseet into txt file using vba - (text and numbers with formulas)

Tags: excel, text-files, vba

I am fairly new to vba but have developed a code to use in excel to move text/numbers to a txt file.  My issue is I currently have three functions that need to go to the same txt file.  When I run it currently the first function has

```
Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.createTextFile(Module1.NYS45Uploadfilename, True)
a.writeline (str)
a.Close.
```

The other two functions had save.

```
Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.saveTextFile(Module1.NYS45Uploadfilename, True)
a.writeline (str)
a.Close.
```

The first function will go to the txt file, the other two I get an error

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

When I changed all three to create the last function goes to the txt file.  I can not figure out what word to use in order to make the other two functions follow into the txt file in the order they are keyed.

The entire code is as follows

```
Private Sub addRecord_Click()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Module1.NYS45Uploadfilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Textfiles (*.txt), *.txt")

    If Module1.NYS45Uploadfilename = "False" Then Exit Sub

    Header_Rec

    Detail_Rec1

    Detail_Rec2

    Dim strmsg As String

    strmsg = "Your file has been added here: " & Module1.NYS45Uploadfilename

    MsgBox strmsg

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    Resume Next

End Sub


Function Header_Rec()

    Dim str, strfilename, txtpath As String

    Dim strlencount, strspacer As Integer

    str = str & Range("a3").Value
    str = str & Range("b3").Value
    str = str & Trim(Range("c3").Value)
    strlencount = Len(Trim(Range("c3").Value))
    strspacer = 30 - strlencount
    str = Module1.SpaceAdd(str, strspacer)
    str = str & Range("d3").Value
    str = str & Range("E3").Value

    str = Module1.SpaceAdd(str, 159)

    ' Debug.Print Len(str)

    Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fs.createTextFile(Module1.NYS45Uploadfilename, True)
    a.writeline (str)
    a.Close
    ' Debug.Print str

End Function

Function Detail_Rec1()

    Dim str, strnum, str2, strfilename, txtpath As String

    Dim strlencount, strspacer As Integer

    If Range("a7").Value <> "5" Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    str = str & Range("a7").Value
    str = str & Range("b7").Value
    str = str & Range("c7").Value

    str = Module1.SpaceAdd(str, 1)
    str = str & Trim(Range("d7").Value)
    strlencount = Len(Trim(Range("d7").Value))
    strspacer = 30 - strlencount
    str = Module1.SpaceAdd(str, strspacer)
    str = str & Range("E7").Value

    ' Debug.Print Len(str)

    Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fs.addTextFile(Module1.NYS45Uploadfilename, True)
    a.writeline (str)
    a.Close
    ' Debug.Print str

End Function

Function Detail_Rec2()

    Dim str, strnum, str2, strfilename, strnew, txtpath As String

    Dim strlencount, strspacer As Integer

    If Range("a11").Value <> "6" Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    str = str & Range("a11").Value
    str = str & Range("b11").Value
    str = str & Trim(Range("c11").Value)
    strlencount = Len(Trim(Range("c11").Value))
    strspacer = 11 - strlencount
    str = Module1.SpaceAdd(str, strspacer)
    strspacer = 30 - strlencount
    str = Module1.SpaceAdd(str, strspacer)
    str = str & Range("f11").Value
    str = str & Range("g11").Value

    ' Debug.Print Len(str)

    Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fs.getTextFile(Module1.NYS45Uploadfilename, True)
    a.writeline (str)
    a.Close
    ' Debug.Print str

End Function
```

Comment: Please edit your question, share the code you use in excel to move text/numbers to a txt file, fix formatting - use code blocks instead of inline codes.

Comment: I apologize what are you asking for?  Do you want the whole code I made for the entire sheet so far?  Can I just copy paste it into here

Comment: there's no such `saveTextFile` method for the `FileSystemObject` object. I get that the "first function" has the goal of creating a `TextStream` object and write into it. But what's the goal of the "other two functions"?

Comment: Each function has a line that is to be created in the txt file.  This txt file is used for testing and uploading to programs to get the result needed. I will include the entire code for you to see.

Comment: but I keep seeing _"strange"_ methods like `getTextFile`, `addTextFile`,... Are you coding in VBA?

Comment: Yes I am.  I am using excel 2010 and coding in VBA

Comment: I am really starting to think it is the wording used in the Set fs = CreateObject.  Where ever the word create is that is the only function that goes to the txt file the other two don't move.  Either there is another word that tells it to send them with the initial file or another code word used

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below example showing how to write text to the file using [`OpenTextFile` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx):

```vb
Sub Test()

    Const ForWriting = 2
    Const ForAppending = 8
    Const FormatDefault = -2
    Const FormatUnicode = -1
    Const FormatASCII = 0

    strFile = "C:\TestFile.txt"

    strText = "New Unicode text file created, this is the first line." & vbCrLf
    WriteTextFile strFile, strText, ForWriting, FormatUnicode

    strText = "New line added, this is the second line." & vbCrLf
    WriteTextFile strFile, strText, ForAppending, FormatUnicode

    strText = "One more line." & vbCrLf
    WriteTextFile strFile, strText, ForAppending, FormatUnicode

End Sub

Sub WriteTextFile(strPath, strContent, lngMode, lngFormat)
    ' strPath: path to the text file
    ' strContent: text to be written to the file
    ' lngMode: 2 - For Writing, 8 - For Appending
    ' lngFormat: -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strPath, lngMode, True, lngFormat)
        .Write strContent
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually figured this out.  My problem was I was asking it to keep going to the file when I should of just asked at the end using a function to export to text.  This is resolved.  Now onto my next issue.  Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: @LizaHunt, if your question has been solved then share the working code as an answer please, or click to accept this answer, that might help someone in future on SO.

Comment: My question wasn't actually answered bc what I was trying to do wasn't going to work.  All I did was instead of doing the create object; I used ExportToText as a function at the end and used hard return coding in each function to create the test file in Notepad.  I am still having trouble making it go to the directory I want but that is more research and hopefully I will figure it out